# ceODBC DatabaseError: no diagnostic message text available

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I am using Mssql with ceODBC, I tried pyodbc but the execute many method was painfully slow and I wanted to try ceODBC.

I created a connection as follows:

```
eODBC.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=%s;port=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s'
```

When I try to insert a row in this pseudocodic-scheme: // Executed query on sql server and also with using pyodbc without any problem.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET VALUES
 ID = 2
 InsertionDateTime = '04/2/2016 12:49:50'
if @@rowcount==0
THEN INSERT VALUES(  ID = 2
 InsertionDateTime = '04/2/2016 12:49:50')
```

I got the following error:

```
ceODBC.DatabaseError: no diagnostic message text available
```

I have no idea about the error and no information, only info is on [ceODBC mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/ceodbc/mailman/message/26388562/) without any solution.

Then I inspected the source code of ceODBC, here is the relevant code snippet:

```
if (rcToCheck == SQL_SUCCESS || rcToCheck == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        return 0;
    if (rcToCheck == SQL_INVALID_HANDLE) {
        PyErr_SetString(g_DatabaseErrorException, "Invalid handle!");
        return -1;
    }

    // create new error object
    error = PyObject_NEW(udt_Error, &g_ErrorType);
    if (!error)
        return -1;
    error->context = context;

    // determine number of diagnostic records available
    rc = SQLGetDiagField(obj->handleType, obj->handle, 0, SQL_DIAG_NUMBER,
            &numRecords, SQL_IS_INTEGER, NULL);
    if (rc != SQL_SUCCESS && rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        error->message = ceString_FromAscii("cannot get number of " \
                "diagnostic records");

    // determine error text
    } else if (numRecords == 0) {
        error->message = ceString_FromAscii("no diagnostic message text " \
                "available");
```

As far as I understant cdODBC gets another response from `SQL_SUCCESS` and `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO` and no records are returned after that.  MSSQL only support these two success messages.

How can I understand/solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after spending a day, i still could not find the cause of the problem. But for me, solution was closing and opening db connection for each time.